# mean.js Unexpected request: GET images

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am a beginner with the test meanjs on the server side. Introduction I have created a service that it calls the factory that performs HTTP. 
So I would like to understand why this error:

> Unexpected request: GET images
>           No more request expected at $httpBackend (/home/developer/mcd2/public/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1181)

```
                            -----MOCK-----
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _$stateParams_, _$httpBackend_,$filter,_Images_) {
            // Set a new global scope
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            // Point global variables to injected services
            $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}

it('Test that takes the complete list of all the images in the DB (Images.get)',inject( function (ImagesREST) {
            var Image = new ImagesREST({
                namefile: 'Image_1',
                width: 123,
                height : 321,
                extension : 'JPG',
                tag : 'pippo',
                size:9998,
                type:'img/jpg',
                path:'/asd/add',
                rel:'/asd/Immagine1',
                lastModified:new Date()
            });

            var arrayImages=[Image];

            $httpBackend.expectGET('images').respond(arrayImages);

            var lista = Images.get();

            $httpBackend.flush();

            console.log(lista);
}));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

it('Test $httpBackend che ritorna la lista delle immagini con get()',inject( function (ImagesREST) {
        var sampleImage = new ImagesREST({
            _id: "542d202ff8e024001a481f70",
            namefile: 'Davide Image',
            width: 235,
            height: 234,
            extension: 'JPG',
            tag: 'dave picture',
            lastMofified: new Date(),
            path: '/home/developer/mcd2/public/modules/uploads/store/images/542d202ff8e024001a481f70/Pippo.jpg',
            rel: 'modules/uploads/store/images/542d202ff8e024001a481f70/Pippo.jpg',
            size:36210,
            type:'image/jpeg'
        });

        // Create a sample Images array that includes the new Image
        var sampleImages = [sampleImage];

        // Set GET response
        $httpBackend.expectGET('images').respond(sampleImages);

        // Run controller functionality
        var ad=Images.get();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(ad).toBeDefined();
        expect(ad._id).toEqualData(sampleImages._id);
        expect(ad.namefile).toEqualData(sampleImages.namefile);
        expect(ad.width).toEqualData(sampleImages.width);
        expect(ad.width).toEqualData(sampleImages.width);
        expect(ad.extension).toEqualData(sampleImages.extension);
        expect(ad.tag).toEqualData(sampleImages.tag);
        expect(ad.lastMofified).toEqualData(sampleImages.lastMofified);
        expect(ad.path).toEqualData(sampleImages.path);
        expect(ad.rel).toEqualData(sampleImages.rel);
        expect(ad.size).toEqualData(sampleImages.size);
        expect(ad.type).toEqualData(sampleImages.type);
    }));
```